# Write portname to a label using setText in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, serial-port, qtserialport

I want to try to show `portname` information in QT. The code is here:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
    {
        qDebug() << "Name : " << info.portName();

        // Example use QSerialPort
        QSerialPort serial;
        serial.setPort(info);
        if (serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
            serial.close();
    }

    ui->label->setText(info.portName());
}
```

When I compile this code this error comes:

> `info` was not declared in this scope

So, what can I do for showing `portname` information to `label`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a really big mistake. I have realized after sharing this question.

The true code must be like that:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
  foreach (const QSerialPortInfo &info, QSerialPortInfo::availablePorts())
  {
        qDebug() << "Name : " << info.portName();
        qDebug() << "Description : " << info.description();
        qDebug() << "Manufacturer: " << info.manufacturer();

        // Example use QSerialPort
        QSerialPort serial;
        serial.setPort(info);
        if (serial.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite))
            serial.close();
   ui->label->setText(info.portName());
}
```

It means that `ui->label->setText(info.portName());` part has to be in parenthesss.